# Wrong AES key length using Crypt::JWT

Tags: perl, crypt, jwe

I'm attempting to generate a JWE with (5 parts) using Crypt::JWT. It's my first foray into perl.

Following the example from the documentation:

```
use Crypt::JWT qw(encode_jwt);

my $claims = {
  iss => 'some issuer',
  cd => 'some cd'
}

my $jws_token = encode_jwt(payload=>$claims, alg=>'HS256', key=>'secret');

my $jwe_token = encode_jwt(payload=>$jws_token, alg=>'dir', enc=>'A256GCM', key=>'secret');
```

I get the error:

```
JWE: wrong AES key length 32 vs 3
```

Other attempt using sha256 on the key first:

```
use Crypt::JWT qw(encode_jwt);
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);

my $key = sha256_hex('secret');

my $claims = {
  iss => 'some issuer',
  cd => 'some cd'
}

my $jws_token = encode_jwt(payload=>$claims, alg=>'HS256', key=>$key);

my $jwe_token = encode_jwt(payload=>$jws_token, alg=>'dir', enc=>'A256GCM', key=>$key);
```

Which gives a similar error:

```
JWE: wrong AES key length 32 vs 64
```

Any pointers would be appreciated?

*P.S: I don't have control over the choice of enc and alg as I'm trying to match the output of a different module*

Comment: With `enc=>'A256GCM'` the key needs to be 32 bytes, see https://funcool.github.io/buddy-sign/latest/01-jwt.html

Comment: See also https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::JWT#key1 which specifies the key length for each

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I misunderstood what's required. It works after generating a sha256 key.